# Code Coverage Failure when deploying Apex Trigger from Sandbox to Prod

Tags: apex, trigger

GM I'm new to apex dev and there are a few things going on with my code and deployment from SB to prod but what I'm struggling to understand is why I'm receiving an error on 'Trace' being a required field when it has nothing to do with my trigger. All I'm looking to do is stop prod users from creating a duplicate inv line on a quote, it was 100% successful in SB but now I'm receiving a 0% code coverage error

**Apex Test Failures**
[image]

Here is my code and test

**apex**

```
trigger NoDuplicateInventoryLine on inscor__Customer_Quote_Line__c (before insert, before update) {
if (Trigger.isBefore) {
    Set<String> inventoryIDs = new Set<String>();
    for (inscor__Customer_Quote_Line__c cql : Trigger.new) {
        if (cql.inscor__Inventory_Line__c != null) {
            inventoryIDs.add(cql.inscor__Inventory_Line__c);
        }
    }
    List<inscor__Customer_Quote_Line__c> existingCQLs = [SELECT inscor__Inventory_Line__c FROM inscor__Customer_Quote_Line__c WHERE inscor__Inventory_Line__c IN :inventoryIDs];
    Set<String> existingIDs = new Set<String>();
    for (inscor__Customer_Quote_Line__c cql : existingCQLs) {
        existingIDs.add(cql.inscor__Inventory_Line__c);
    }
    for (inscor__Customer_Quote_Line__c cql : Trigger.new) {
        if (existingIDs.contains(cql.inscor__Inventory_Line__c)) {
            cql.addError('Do not allow duplicate Inventory ID');
        }
    }
}
```

**test**

```
@isTest
public class PreventInventoryLineDuplicateTest {
    @isTest
    public static void testPreventInventoryLineDuplicate() {
        // create a test Inventory Line record
        inscor__Inventory_Line__c invLine = new inscor__Inventory_Line__c();
        insert invLine;
        
        // create a test Customer Quote Line record with the same Inventory Line ID
        inscor__Customer_Quote_Line__c cql1 = new inscor__Customer_Quote_Line__c(inscor__Inventory_Line__c = invLine.Id);
        insert cql1;
        
        // attempt to insert a second Customer Quote Line record with the same Inventory Line ID
        inscor__Customer_Quote_Line__c cql2 = new inscor__Customer_Quote_Line__c(inscor__Inventory_Line__c = invLine.Id);
        Test.startTest();
        try {
            insert cql2;
            System.assert(false, 'validation error for duplicate Inventory ID');
        } catch (DmlException e) {
            System.assert(e.getMessage().contains('Do not allow duplicate Inventory ID'));
        }
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be helpful TIA

Comment: Your unit tests are executed in the org that you're trying to deploy to, so if there are additional required fields you will need to make sure that your test sets them. If you're using `@isTest(seeAllData=true)`, you should almost certainly not be (that breaks test data isolation, and you should be explicitly creating test data). Please [edit] your question to include your test class (which is what the error is complaining about).

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger code may be fine. The error is occurring in the ReceiveFullDataBarcodeController_Test class. It's hard to tell from your post if this test class is for your trigger or not.

Test classes often create test data for testing purposes. When first deployed, these work fine, but can sometimes break if additional field requirements are added to an object created by the test class without updating the test class itself.

You could consider deploying your code with the "Run Specified Tests" option and list only those test classes related to your code. This would alleviate the need to solve an error in unrelated code.

If this test class is for your code, you'd need to review the runTest2 method in the ReceiveFullDataBarcodeController_Test class and add the Trace__c field as a datapoint to the records being created in that class. It would appear that your production environment requires the Trace__c field for the object that the test class is creating, and the SB environment you developed in did not.

Comment: ty Nick I'll update and try

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Salesforce world!

```
inscor__Inventory_Line__c invLine = new inscor__Inventory_Line__c();
/* add something like this
invLine.Trace__c = 'XXX';
*/
insert invLine;
```

As the exception says the `Trace__c` field is required and you need to add something there based on the field Data Type.
TIP: you can also check what are the other required fields and populate the test record accordingly.

P.S. nick frates also had good points about the test classes you are selecting during the deployment. It's good to add to the changeset only APEX classes and tests you want to deploy and select only these test classes to run when accepting the change request